# Rails: How to make Date strftime aware of the default locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, rails-i18n, strftime

I have my default locale set in the `environment.rb` as `de` (German).

I also see all the error messages in German, so the locale is picked up by the server. But when I try to print date with `strftime` like following:

```
some_date.strftime('%B, %y')
```

It prints in English (`January, 11`), and not the expected German (`Januar, 11`).

How can I print the date according to the default locale?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the `l` (alias for `localize`) method instead of raw strftime, like this:

```
l(date, format: '%B %d, in the year %Y')
```

See [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) for more information.

You can also define 'named' formats, a couple of them (`short`, `long`) are already predefined.

Comment: How to print the date in format with localize ? Does it accept any formatting string like '%B, %y' ?

Comment: I figured it out: I18n.localize(some_date, :format => '%B, %y' Thanks

Comment: You'll want to make sure you have this gem installed: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n  That way you can have different locale's and call their `format: short` or whatever you'd like to reference.  Look here for examples on references: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

Comment: Or you can do something like this once you have that gem I mentioned above installed... `l @item.created_at, :format => "%b %e, %Y", :locale => 'en'`

Answer (score 30):

you can also make it shorter:

```
l(some_date, :format => '%d %B %Y')
```

Answer (score 10):

In es.yml put:

```
es:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d / %m / %Y"
```

In index.html.erb put:

```
<%= l somemodel.datefield %>
```

Comment: Should it be `time` instead of `date` actually? It depends of the Class of the object passed I believe.